# Fetch the count for no of occurence in a array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

```
var json = [{
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Joe",
        "age": 17
    }, {
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 17
    }, {
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35
    }, {
        "city": "Texas",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35
    }, {
        "city": "Florida",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35
    }
];
```

I just to no of occurence based on city value i.e output as below.

```
updatedjson=[{"name":"California","count":3},{"name":"Texas","count":1},{"name":"Florida","count":1}]
```

using any approah using lodash or javascript

Comment: occurences of what?

Comment: occurence of particular key value.in in example above city:"California" occurence is 3 times so i want want to frame array as provided in updatedjson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Lodash, that would be:

```
const updatedJson = _(json)
                     .countBy('city')
                     .map((count, name) => ({ name, count }))
                     .value();
```

```js
const json = [{"city":"California","name":"Joe","age":17},{"city":"California","name":"Bob","age":17},{"city":"California","name":"Bob","age":35},{"city":"Texas","name":"Bob","age":35},{"city":"Florida","name":"Bob","age":35}];

const updatedJson = _(json)
  .countBy('city')
  .map((count, name) => ({ name, count }))
  .value();
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedJson));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = [{
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Joe",
        "age": 17
    }, {
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 17
    }, {
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35
    }, {
        "city": "Texas",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35
    }, {
        "city": "Florida",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35
    }
];

var hash = {}; // will be used for lookup of index of city in updated_json array.
var updated_json = [];
json.forEach(function(item,index){
  // if city exists in hash then retrive its position from hash.
  if(item.city in hash){
    updated_json[hash[item.city]].count++;
  }
  else{
    hash[item.city] = updated_json.length; // store position
    updated_json.push({"name":item.city,"count":1});
  }
});

console.log(updated_json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will get it:

```
updatedJson = [
    {
       name: "California", 
       count: (_.filter(json, item => item.city === "California").length)
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the count with [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and render the result with the wanted properties.

```js
var data = [{ city: "California", name: "Joe", age: 17 }, { city: "California", name: "Bob", age: 17 }, { city: "California", name: "Bob", age: 35 }, { city: "Texas", name: "Bob", age: 35 }, { city: "Florida", name: "Bob", age: 35 }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { city }) => m.set(city, (m.get(city) || 0) + 1), new Map),
        ([name, count]) => ({ name, count })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```