# Fetch the no of of occurence in a array based on other key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

```
var json = [{
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Joe",
        "age": 17,
        "type",:"custom"
    }, {
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 17,
        "type",:"predefined"
    }, {
        "city": "California",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35,
        "type",:"custom"
    }, {
        "city": "Texas",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35,
        "type",:"custom"
    }, {
        "city": "Florida",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": 35,
        "type",:"predefined"
 }];
```

I have above array and i have to construct object, based on "type" value i.e "predefined" or "custom" as below

```
updatedjson = {
    "predefined": [{
            "name": "California",
            "count": 1
        }, {
            "name": "Florida",
            "count": 1
        }]
     "custom": [{
            "name": "California",
            "count": 2
        }, {
            "name": "Texas",
            "count": 1
        }]
 }
```

Any Approach using javascript or lodash

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050863/fetch-the-count-for-no-of-occurence-in-a-array-of-object

Comment: No this is different

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried already to achieve that result?

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid at `"type",`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch the count for no of occurence in a array of object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050863/fetch-the-count-for-no-of-occurence-in-a-array-of-object)

Comment: Question is great, and new.

Just avoid using example JSONs belonging to other questions asked on Stack Overflow to avoid being flagged as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using Lodash

```js
var json = [{
  "city": "California",
  "name": "Joe",
  "age": 17,
  "type": "custom"
}, {
  "city": "California",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 17,
  "type": "predefined"
}, {
  "city": "California",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 35,
  "type": "custom"
}, {
  "city": "Texas",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 35,
  "type": "custom"
}, {
  "city": "Florida",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 35,
  "type": "predefined"
}];

// Solution to the problem

var updatedJson = _(json).groupBy("type").value();    // #1

_.forOwn(updatedJson, function(value, key) {
  let countByCity = _(value).countBy('city').value(); // #2
  let res = [];

  _.forOwn(countByCity, function(value, key) {
    res.push({                                        // #3
      name: key,
      count: value
    });
  });

  updatedJson[key] = res;
});

console.log(updatedJson);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

> Explanation

1. Code first groups by type
2. Then counts by cities, within the group
3. Finally pushes the count object into an array, in the expected format

Comment: Thank you so much!!...is there simpler way using lodash

Comment: @gauthamshetty I have replaced the vanilla JS code with Lodash

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a new object with the aggregated data. Example:

```
  const result = json.reduce((obj, data) => {
      // if this is a new type, we must initialize it as an empty array and push the first record.
      if(!obj[data.type]) {
        obj[data.type] = [];
        obj[data.type].push({name: data.city, count: 1});
        return obj;
      }
      // else ... check if the current city is present in that type
      const existingRecord = obj[data.type].find(d => d.name === data.city);
      if(!existingRecord) {
         // if the city is not present in that type, we initialize it with count 1
         obj[data.type].push({name: data.city, count: 1});
         return obj;
      }
      // if the city is present, we just update count = count + 1;
      existingRecord.count++;
      return obj;
    }, { })
```

Now, you probably want to extract some of that logic into separate functions to increase readability. I don't think you need lodash for this but in the case you already have it included in your project then feel free to use it :P

Comment: here type can be anything can have value other than predefined and custom

Comment: I didn't know that was a necessity, check my updated snippet, I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` & `findIndex`

```js
var json = [{
  "city": "California",
  "name": "Joe",
  "age": 17,
  "type": "custom"
}, {
  "city": "California",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 17,
  "type": "predefined"
}, {
  "city": "California",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 35,
  "type": "custom"
}, {
  "city": "Texas",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 35,
  "type": "custom"
}, {
  "city": "Florida",
  "name": "Bob",
  "age": 35,
  "type": "predefined"
}];

var updatedjson = json.reduce(function(result, item) {
  // check if type is present in the object
  // if not present then add a key by name custom/predefined
  if (!result[item.type]) {
    result[item.type] = [];
    // add city name and intial count
    result[item.type].push({
      name: item.city,
      count: 1
    })
  } else {
    // now find the index of the object whe name matches with current city
    let m = result[item.type].findIndex(function(obj) {
      return obj.name === item.city
    })
    // if no matches then add the new object to either custom/predefined
    if (m === -1) {
      result[item.type].push({
        name: item.city,
        count: 1
      })
    } else {
      // if matches then increase the value of count
      result[item.type][m].count += 1
    }

  }
  return result;

}, {});

console.log(updatedjson)
```

Comment: Thank yoy so much!.Cant we do this using lodash