# merge javascript array values with same key

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to re-organize array into output? I need to merge the values with the same key into an array of objects.

the input array:

```
 var array = [
    {
      aaa: {
        name: "foo1",
        value: "val1"
      }
    }, 
    { 
      aaa: {
        name: "foo2",
        value: "val2"
      }
    },
    {
     bbb: {
        name: "foo3",
        value: "val3"
      }
    },
    {
      bbb: {
        name: "foo4",
        value: "val4"
      }
    }
];
```

The desired output:

```
var output = [
   { 
    aaa: 
        [{
            name: "foo1",
            value: "val1"
        },{
        name: "foo2",
        value: "val2"
    }]
   },
   {
    bbb: 
        [{
            name: "foo3",
            value: "val3"
        },{
        name: "foo4",
        value: "val4"
    }]
  }

];
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That array is invalid.

Comment: **Did you mean:** `{ aaa: {
        name: "foo1",
        value: "val1"
    }}`

Comment: yes... im sorry.. im changing the question

Comment: Also, please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really help us to figure out the issue with your code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch the no of of occurence in a array based on other key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055027/fetch-the-no-of-of-occurence-in-a-array-based-on-other-key-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`

```js
var array = [{aaa: {name: "foo1",value: "val1"}},{aaa: {name: "foo2",value: "val2"}},{bbb: {name: "foo3",value: "val3"}},{bbb: {name: "foo4",value: "val4"}}];

var newArray = array.reduce((c, v) => {
  for (var k in v) {
    c[k] = c[k] || [];
    c[k].push(v[k]);
  }
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(newArray);
```

Doc: [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` and `forEach` function.

```js
var array = [{    aaa: {      name: "foo1",      value: "val1"    }  },  {    aaa: {      name: "foo2",      value: "val2"    }  },  {    bbb: {      name: "foo3",      value: "val3"    }  },  {    bbb: {      name: "foo4",      value: "val4"    }  }];

var result = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  Object.keys(c).forEach((k) => { 
    if (a[k]) {
      a[k].push(c[k]);
    } else {
      a[k] = [c[k]];
    }
  })
  
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```